# Reload footerView of UICollectionViewCell with reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a CollectionView to display data. When the user presses a certain button, I am refreshing the CollectionViewCell to reflect the changes like this:

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
```

This works fine to reload the cell, except it doesn't reload it's footer view. I implemented the following method

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"FOOTER CALLED");
```

This doesn't get called when I reload the cell.

Eveything works if I reload the whole collection view with [self.collectionview reloadData], but this is not efficient.

How to make sure the Footer of my UICollectionViewCell at indexPath gets refreshed also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **invalidate** the layout or **reload** the section.

1. Invalidating the layout.

   ```
   [[_collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout]
   ```
2. Reloading the section. Use `reloadSections:` to update 1 or more sections in the `UICollectionView`.

   ```
   [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]];
   ```

Comment: I implemented both in that order and it solved my problem, thank you! For those having the same problem and wondering what values should go in NSMakeRange: NSMakeRange works with (location, length). NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex-startIndex). Because I wanted to refresh element at indexPath.row, I used NSMakeRange(indexPath.row, indexPath.row).